# How to add between date filter on PIVOT SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored data with types and date recorded. I would like to get the total of each type per date. I have a [Transactions] table with the following pattern:

```
Id |   Type   |      Date_and_Time      |
----------------------------------------
1  |   Bags   | 2019-01-01 17:39:34.620 |
2  |   Shoes  | 2019-01-02 17:39:34.620 |
3  |   Shoes  | 2019-01-02 17:39:34.620 |
4  |   Bags   | 2019-01-02 17:39:34.620 | 
5  |  Shirts  | 2019-01-02 17:39:34.620 |
6  |  Shirts  | 2019-01-03 17:39:34.620 |
7  |  Shirts  | 2019-01-03 17:39:34.620 |  
...
```

I have working PIVOT query but without date filter:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Type) 
             FROM   Transactions
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL);

EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
                   from  #Tempsa GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt')

Output :
Transaction_Date |  Bags | Shirts | Shoes
------------------------------------------
|   2019-01-01   |  1    |  NULL  | NULL |
|   2019-01-02   |  1    |  1     | 2    |
|   2019-01-03   |  NULL |  2     | NULL |
....
```

However, when I use the below query with between date filter I don't get any record:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/03/2019'

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Type) 
             FROM   #Tempsa
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL);

EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
                   from  #Tempsa WHERE Date_and_Time BETWEEN ' +@STARTDATE+ ' AND ' +@ENDDATE+' GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt')


Output :
Transaction_Date |  Bags | Shirts | Shoes
------------------------------------------
|                |       |        |       |
....
```

Comment: Hi, have you try to use : where CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) BETWENN CAST('+@STARTDATE+ '  as DATE) AND CAST(' +@ENDDATE+' as DATE) / ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add quotes around the date:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/03/2019'

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Type) 
             FROM   #Tempsa
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL);

EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
                   from  #Tempsa WHERE Date_and_Time BETWEEN ''' +@STARTDATE+ ''' AND ''' +@ENDDATE+''' GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt')
```

Without double quotes, you are building something like this:

```
BETWEEN 01/01/2011 AND 01/03/2019
```

which is just a calculation that is evaluated by the engine

```
 SELECT 01/01/2011 -- 0
       ,01/03/2019 -- 0
```

and it is `0`. So, you are asking to get all dates which are from `0` to `0`. 
And that's why adding the quotes make your filtering criteria valid (it was valid before, but `SELECT CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` and as your boundaries are the same, no records are returned).

Of course, you can use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @STARTDATE, 121)` to ensure there are no misunderstandings during the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the query shared by you to get the desired result. it was not working because single quite was missing while concatenating the date for the filter. Now it is working. You can verify the same.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/03/2019'

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Type) 
             FROM   #Tempsa
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL);

EXECUTE( 'SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
                   from  #Tempsa WHERE Date_and_Time BETWEEN ''' + @STARTDATE+ ''' AND ''' +@ENDDATE+''' GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your dates on ISO format so you don't get month and day mixed up.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '2019-01-03'
```

And make sure (just in case) to explicitly convert them on your dynamic SQL. Also it's a good approach to set your SQL to a variable and preview it first before executing (with PRINT):

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
    from  #Tempsa WHERE Date_and_Time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, ''' +@STARTDATE+ ''') AND CONVERT(DATE, ''' + @ENDDATE +''') 
    GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt'

PRINT (@DynamicSQL)

-- EXECUTE(@DynamicSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your query, you can use `sp_executesql` with parameter like following.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/01/2019'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '01/03/2019'

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(Type) 
             FROM   #Tempsa
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL);

declare @SQLString Nvarchar(max)= N'SELECT * FROM (select CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, Type, Count(*) n 
                   from  #Tempsa WHERE Date_and_Time BETWEEN @SD  AND @ED GROUP BY CAST(Date_and_Time as DATE), Type) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR Type IN (' +@cols + ')) pvt'
exec sp_executesql @SQLString,N'@SD DATE,@ED DATE',@SD=@STARTDATE,@ED=@ENDDATE
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/DOG66950)